# How to detect if the CMD or Shift key has been pressed during a NSPressGestureRecognizer event?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsevent

In the handler of an press gesture recognizer I try to find out if CMD or Shift has been pressed, like this:

```
- (void)handlePress:(NSPressGestureRecognizer*)gr {
    NSEventModifierFlags flags = [[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags];
    if (flags & NSCommandKeyMask) {
        NSLog(@"CMD pressed");
    }
}
```

However the flag is only set correctly in a keyDown or keyUp event handler method. NSGestureRecognizer doesn't seem to expose the event object thus I get the currentEvent it from NSApp. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right. Check [keyDown](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGestureRecognizer/keyDown:) method description of NSGestureRecognizer class: "A gesture recognizer monitors events that occur in its view (and any subviews) but does not take part in the responder chain itself. The gesture recognizer receives events before any views do. Use the delaysKeyEvents property to control whether event is propagated to the view. "

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subclassing, you can use `NSGestureRecognizerDelegate` like so:

```
extension ViewController : NSGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldAttemptToRecognizeWith event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return event.modifierFlags.contains(.command)
    }
}
```

Technically, this will only recognize modifier keys held at the time the mouse went down, but from a UI standpoint, that could be what you want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing NSPressGestureRecognizer to collect the modifier flags from the mouse down event.

```
class PressGestureRecognizer: NSPressGestureRecognizer {
var modifierFlags = NSEventModifierFlags (rawValue: 0)

override func flagsChanged (with event: NSEvent) {
    super.flagsChanged (with: event)
    modifierFlags = event.modifierFlags
}

override func mouseDown (with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown (with: event)
    modifierFlags = event.modifierFlags
}
```

}